# xcode framework & API?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am new to iphone development, but my question is for example,

resignFirstResponder

Where you guys found that? Is that considered a built-in function in xcode framework/API? Where do I find those built-in ones or API to use on my learning projects to see which one I need?

Comment: It's part of the iOS SDK.  Go through some books like: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596523190.do

Comment: For iOS classes, search for XXX Class Reference and XXX Programming Guide.  For example, search for UIView class reference and UIView Programming guide for a reference and guide to the UIView which is part of the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a project open in Xcode and you see a call like that you can typically:

cmd-click on that method call to show the declaration.

opt-click on the method call to see documentation, if any is available.

But, if you are new to iPhone development, this is the last place you should start.  You should start at the overviews, concept guides, etc... and work down to needing to know about individual methods.

Specifically, [start here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html).